# Jenkins not triggering gerrit verify +1 after successfull build

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

My Jenkins version is 2.32.2, Gerrit is 2.14.1. When I made push to gerrit I can see that my voter starts. However, after successful building following ssh message is sent to gerrit by jenkins:

gerrit review 392,1 --message 'Build Successfull http://jenkins/job/voter/298/ : SUCCESS' --verified 0 --code-review 0

I've already checked gerrit plugin settings and as I can see correct vote for verify label is set. Please, see screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrrQ5.png). Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) Check: Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Gerrit Trigger > Edit > Advanced... > Gerrit Verified Commands > Successful 2) Check: Job >  Configure > Gerrit Trigger > Advanced... > Gerrit Reporting Values > Verify > Succesful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved itself somehow. Magic :)

Comment: The most classic of solutions!